# Types of notification that I can use in APEX

Tags: apex, notification, push-notification, event-notification-service

I am just wondering, what are all the notifications that I can use with Salesforce/APEX? I mean, currently I can add notification in a lightning component with the  ([lightning:notificationsLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation))

or I can also add a notification with [CustomNotification Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Messaging_CustomNotification.htm)

but I can see that there is a third type of notifications, like the image below (little pop up in the bottom-right of the browser), is it possible to trigger a notification of this style via APEX? are they any other notifications that I am missing?

[image: Salesforce Notification]

Comment: Well I believe inserting tasks gives you a bell notification, which I do not believe is what  is reflected in your screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a notification, it's an [In App Guidance](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customhelp_lexguid.htm&type=5). You can create your own and trigger them in various ways. You can monitor which of your users have viewed these IAGs, and more. To have more than three active IAGs on a user, they must be assigned a myTrailhead license (additional costs may apply).

However, since you've asked specifically about notifications, I'll include a short list for those, too, for the ones I remember. This answer will be a Community Wiki to lower the bar for editing.

- ConnectAPI (Apex)
- sObject FeedItem (REST/SOAP/Apex)
- Salesforce Chatter REST API (any API client)
- lightning/platformShowToastEvent (LWC)
- lightning:notificationsLibrary (Aura)
- Other standard bell notifications (e.g. being assigned a Task)

Comment: Cool, I am using custom notification however, sometimes users dont look at the little bell, I was trying to have a more visible message I guess I have to stick with the little bell :)

Comment: @manza Yeah, that's really the best option for regular notifications, I guess. You can try Chatter, too, but that can require extra setup.